# ServiceStack OpenAPI Route/Tag Description

Tags: c#, servicestack, swagger-ui, servicestack-openapi

I've upgraded my project to use the latest version of ServiceStack and to use the OpenApiFeature instead of the SwaggerFeature.

The descriptions I specified in the RouteSummary used to display in Swagger, but under OpenApi they don't seem to be respected. Is there a new place for these or am I missing something in my config?

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    RouteSummary = {
        { "/clubs", "Customer club lookups" },
        { "/customers", "Customer demographics, receipts and transactions" },
        { "/dates", "Fiscal date breakdowns" }
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SwaggerFeature` follows the Swagger 1.2 Specification which decoupled the list of APIs from their specification where the API [Resource Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#512-resource-object) allowed you to specify a **description** for a collection of routes. However the combined Open API Specification in the [Open API v2.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) specification removed this feature.

This has been replaced with [Open API Tags](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#tagObject), which I've added explicit support for in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a71a8a5ff3b91bf5eaf975d467edb71f37258c2a) where you can group operations you want displayed together using the same tag, e.g:

```
[Tag("clubs")]
[Route("/clubs", "GET")]
public class GetClubs {}

[Tag("clubs")]
[Route("/clubs/{Id}", "PUT")]
public class UpdateClub 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

You can then specify a description for each tag when registering the `OpenApiFeature`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature
{
    Tags =
    {
        new OpenApiTag
        {
            Name = "clubs",
            Description = "Customer club lookups",
        },
        new OpenApiTag
        {
            Name = "customers",
            Description = "Customer demographics, receipts and transactions",
        },
        new OpenApiTag
        {
            Name = "dates",
            Description = "Fiscal date breakdowns",
        },
    }
});
```

The new `Tags` collection is available from **v4.5.13** that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks for adding support for this so quickly. You're awesome!